# Copy data to nested list

Tags: .net, sql-server, silverlight, nested-lists

I've some students' records in database and I need to show that data to user in nested grid. Data is like

### Name - Age - Subject - Obt.Marks - TotalMarks

```
Ali      20     Maths           80             100
Ali      20     Literature      60             100
Ali      20     English         80             100
Ahmad    20     Maths           70             100
Ahmad    20     Literature      60             100
Ahmad    20     English         90             100
John     20     Maths           80             100
John     20     Literature      80             100
John     20     English         80             100
```

I've nested list that has student Name, age and List of each student marks and subjects. But I don't understand how to copy data from database to list without repeating any student.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a classic master/detail scenario where you can set up two grids, one with student data and one with marks. Upon selecting a row in the student grid, the marks grid will populate with data relating to the selected student.
There is another option. You can use the deprecated DataGrid and bind to a DataTable that is connected by a DataRelation to acheive a nested UI. You will have to specifically add this control to the toolbox because you will only be shown the newer DataGridView.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtStudents = new DataTable("Students");
        dtStudents.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("StudentID", typeof(Int32)));
        dtStudents.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
        dtStudents.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Age", typeof(Int32)));

        DataTable dtMarks = new DataTable("Marks");
        dtMarks.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("StudentID", typeof(Int32)));
        dtMarks.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Mark", typeof(Int32)));

        DataRow dr = dtStudents.NewRow();
        dr["StudentID"] = 100;
        dr["Name"] = "Bob";
        dr["Age"] = 20;
        dtStudents.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dtStudents.NewRow();
        dr["StudentID"] = 200;
        dr["Name"] = "Sally";
        dr["Age"] = 10;
        dtStudents.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dtStudents.NewRow();
        dr["StudentID"] = 300;
        dr["Name"] = "Joe";
        dr["Age"] = 30;
        dtStudents.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dtMarks.NewRow();
        dr["StudentID"] = 100;
        dr["Mark"] = 80;
        dtMarks.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dtMarks.NewRow();
        dr["StudentID"] = 100;
        dr["Mark"] = 70;
        dtMarks.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dtMarks.NewRow();
        dr["StudentID"] = 100;
        dr["Mark"] = 60;
        dtMarks.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dtMarks.NewRow();
        dr["StudentID"] = 200;
        dr["Mark"] = 80;
        dtMarks.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dtMarks.NewRow();
        dr["StudentID"] = 200;
        dr["Mark"] = 80;
        dtMarks.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dtMarks.NewRow();
        dr["StudentID"] = 300;
        dr["Mark"] = 75;
        dtMarks.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dtMarks.NewRow();
        dr["StudentID"] = 100;
        dr["Mark"] = 99;
        dtMarks.Rows.Add(dr);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dtStudents);
        ds.Tables.Add(dtMarks);

        DataRelation drStudentId = new DataRelation(
            "StudentID_Relation", ds.Tables[0].Columns["StudentID"],
            ds.Tables[1].Columns["StudentID"], true);

        ds.Relations.Add(drStudentId);
        dataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Students"];           

    }
}
```

And you get a UI like these: "+" signs in the row header to expand to child data.
[image: Parent data shown collapsed]
[image: Expanding the parent row]
[image: And finally the child rows]

Comment: With Linq to Entities or some other object relational mapped, you can get lists back from the database without repeating data.